# Clearing color of GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY with PBO

Tags: opengl

I have a texture 2d array of TEXTURE_2D.I need to clear the content of the textures before each draw pass.I am trying to do it with PBO.But I am getting INVALID_OPERATION error.

**Here is how I create the array of images:**

```
glGenTextures(1,&_texID);
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,_texID);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,1,GL_RGBA32F,width,height,numTextures);      
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,0);
glBindImageTexture(0, _texID, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
```

**Here is how I clear it:**

```
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, clearBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, itexArray->GetTexID());
for(int i =0; i <numTextures ;++i) {
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,1,0, 0, 0, _viewportWidth, _viewportHeight, i , GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
```

I have numTextures = 8,so 8 texture layers in the array.When I start clearing them in the loop,first 4 are cleared without errors but from the forth on I ma getting INVALID_OPERATION.

**UPDATE:**

I solved PBO INVALID_OPERATION issue by enlarging PBO size from 2048x2048 to 4096x4096 but the result is that the textures of texture array are still not cleared properly.For example,at startup of the program leftovers can be still seen which disappear only after the rendered objects start moving around the viewport.

Here is the setup for clearing PBO:

```
GLint frameSize =MAX_FRAMEBUFFER_WIDTH * MAX_FRAMEBUFFER_HEIGHT * sizeof(float);
glGenBuffers(1, &clearBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER,clearBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER,frameSize,NULL,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//fill the buffer with color:
vec4* data = (vec4*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER,GL_WRITE_ONLY);
memset(data,0x00,frameSize);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

Where MAX_FRAMEBUFFER_WIDTH  and MAX_FRAMEBUFFER_HEIGHT  are both 4096

Comment: By the way, instead of a mapped memset you can also do a [`glClearBufferData`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearBufferData.xml) since GL 4.3. Too bad this doesn't exist for textures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `glTexSubImage3D` call is broken.

```
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, 
                0, 0, 0,                              //offset (first image)
                _viewportWidth, _viewportHeight, i,   //size (getting larger)
                GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

First of all, of course *Vasaka* is right in that you shouldn't write to mipmap level `1` (which doesn't even exist), but `0`. But even then this call will try to put a 3D image of size `_viewportWidth * _viewportHeight * i` at the first array index, which is surely not what you want. Instead you want to clear a 2D image of size `_viewportWidth * _viewportHeight` *at* position `i`. So your call should actually look this way:

```
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 
                0, 0, i,                               //offset (ith image)
                _viewportWidth, _viewportHeight, 1,    //size (proper 2D image)
                GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

And your problem with needing a larger PBO than neccessary is easily solved by including a `4` in the computation of `frameSize`. Your PBO is treated (and explained by you) as containing 4-vectors of `float`s, yet you compute the size in bytes of it as if it just contained single `float`s. That's why it magically works for a doubled dimension, since this would properly increase the size of the PBO 4 times, as neccessary, but it only hides the actual problem of forgetting the component count in the size computation.

**EDIT:** By the way, instead of maintaining a huge PBO which contains nothing but `0`s, you could also try to attach the respective image layer to an FBO and do a simple `glClear` in each loop iteration. Don't know which one is more efficient (but I'd guess `glClear` being more optimized than a whole image copy), but it at least makes this large PBO obsolete.

Comment: That explains me alot...For the FBO clearing,don't you think that attaching layers and detaching them after clearing will cause more overhead than using PBO?

Comment: @MichaelIV Like said, don't know which one is faster, but it certainly spares you that large PBO. And like said, I'd think clearing might itself be faster than a large image copy, maybe even so much that it alleviates the attaching overhead (don't know how big that is, but I'd wonder if it was nearly as heavy as an image copy).

Comment: @MichaelIV So does it work now (hint: it should, except if you had a completely unrelated other problem not shown in your question)?

Comment: Yes it seems like it does.But what then is the meaning of depth =1.I thought depth param is the z index of the array...Is it mipmap depth?

Comment: @MichaelIV Neither of both. You are using `glTexSubImage3D`. With this function you can update an arbitrary **3D** region of a 3D texture (and a 2D array in this case is nothing but a 3D texture). So the depth parameter is the 3rd dimension of the size of this region. But you want to update a single 2D image in the array, so your depth is 1. The index inside the array is the zoffset argument. Like I've written, you have 3 coordinates for the position inside the 3D texture and 3 sizes for the size of the 3D region to update.

Comment: @MichaelIV If in doubt, what always helps is [the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage3D.xml) and is usually better than looking at examples and trying to figure out the meaning of function paramters yourself. In the end you could have used `glTexSubImage3D` to update the whole texture array at once, but this would have required your already pretty useless 0-buffer to be even larger.

Answer (score 3):

Level is level of detail, i.e. mipmap level, in most cases it is 0, depth would be array index in your case.

Comment: @MichaelIV Well, what does your PBO contain?

Comment: @MichaelIV you asking for one level of storage with glTexStorage3D, but clear second mip level with index 1, most likely you should set level 0 in the glTexSubImage3D call since level 1 does not exist.


Also one style note, last param in the glTexSubImage3D call is byte offset into clearBuffer in your case, it would be more readable if it is 0 instead of NULL.

Comment: Null  or zero shouldn't matter. But what I found is the size of clearing PBO does matter. It was set to be 2048 x2048. And it failed after FORTH texture. Now I scaled it to 4096 x4096 and now it doesn't throw invalid pbo operation ...

Comment: @MichaelIV clearing mip level 1 while you only asked storage for 0 mip level still bothers me, this should not work unless you did something in between.

Comment: That thing is zero now, still it doesn't clear all the images.

Comment: @MichaelIV show also code where you attach data to unpack buffer please.

Comment: @MichaelIV Of course you need a 4 times bigger PBO, since you forgot the 4 in the size computation (as you previously claimed it contains `float[4]`s).